# How do I save a Hashmap which contains a class?

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm having troubles saving and loading a hashmap in a YAML file. The problem  is that my hashmap contains a class inside it.

So here is my hashmap:

```
public static Hashmap<String, Clans> playersClan = new Hashmap<>();
```

Here is my attempt to save and load it into yamlfile

```
public void onEnable() {

  for(String key : this.getConfig().getKeys(true))  {
      //Getting a red line while trying to convert the string to a clans object!
      Clans value = new Clans(this.getConfig().getString(key));
      Clans.playersClan.put(key, value);

  }
}

public void onDisable() {

    for(Entry<String, Clans> entry : Clans.playersClan.entrySet()){

        this.getConfig().set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());

    }
    saveConfig();
}
```

Errors that I need help to fix:

1. Line 15 : I'm trying to convert a object of my class Clans using the `toString()` method and some people already told me that it is not possible < to do it with the `toString()` method.
2. Line 5 While I'm trying to convert the string to an class object. Of  course if the conversion of the object to a string is wrong this one is  wrong as well. Apart of that I'm getting a red line too.

So, basically, I need help converting strings to objects of classes, and  objects of classes to strings.

I'm working with the bukkit API.

Comment: Did you have a look at Serialization (e.g., http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)?

Comment: Yes i have, but i couldnt do it with a object being a class

Comment: What do you mean with "an object being a class"? A `Class` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) in Java is `Serializable`, so you can do that and every `Object` in Java is `Serializable`, if you implement it that way (i.e., write the class so that the object is serializable).

Comment: Sorry my english is not good. What i meant is i need to serialize my hashmap and save it to a file. Firstoble, would the toString() method do that work for me?

Comment: No, it won't... have a look at my first comment. It explains on how to serialize and deserialize an object.

Comment: But im already using the constructor of my class Clans to create a new Clan, so it needs a String param. Im a bit confuse... My class:http://pastebin.com/ In the tutorial it shows how to serialize strings and i need  to serialize a hashmap and a list

Comment: In the example it serializes a `Employee` not a `String`. The result of a serialization is always a `byte[]`, which can be easily stored in a file. The example also shows how you can deserialize an `Object`. In your case, make sure that your `Clans` class implements `Serializable` and then just follow the example from tutorialspoint.

Comment: Use google: http://www.mkyong.com/java-best-practices/understand-the-serialversionuid/

Comment: Please take a few moments to review the edits that I made to your post. A properly formatted post (no need for `</br>`) with the actual small piece of code included, without thanks and proper spelling ( `i`, `im`?) is more likely to get attention and thereby a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can save an instance of a class as YAML by converting it to a string representation yourself, but that would not be using your YAML library.

Mixing using your library for dumping the hashmap and switching to "manually" dumping your `Clans` instances will be quite difficult to manage, you would need to know e.g. how far to indent your string, how to deal with recursive references in your data, with complex attributes etc. So that is not the correct approach.

Your instances should be written out a **tagged YAML mapping**. The tag will direct the YAML library when *loading* to re-create a Clans type instance and the populate this instance's state from the attributes. Because of the possible recursion, which is supported by YAML using anchor and references, this is normally done in a two step process.

For all instances YAML needs to know how to dump them. Some directly map to the YAML primitive scalars (integers, strings, boolean, etc.), others directly map to its data structures (sequence and mapping). Your library could directly map your `Hashmap` to a YAML mapping without you having to do anything (this is your library designers decision). For **all other objects** you *may* need to tell how to dump (and load) instances of the object class to a mapping but in that case you never **serialise** to YAML scalar strings yourself, you might have to tell the library how a particular attribute (e.g a four byte value representing an IPv4 address) maps to a string.

E.g. `snakeyaml` and `YamlBeans` show in their examples they don't have to be told how to dump instances of specific classes.

If so that is often done by subclassing some special  How that is done depends on the YAML library you are using.

The only reason you would need help converting objects to strings and strings to objects is when you are writing your own YAML library. From experience I can recommend thinking twice before doing so.